# Tableau - KPI (Forms) using different variables

Tags: forms, tableau-api, kpi

Im trying to perform a KPI on Tableau based on the `rank` of certain variables such as `sales` and `profit` as the excel example below

[image]

KPI = If the country position (using `rank` formula on Tableau) is on TOP 3 = GREEN; TOP 5 = YELOW; OTHER = RED. As the second table shows

On Tableau, I would have to create 2 calculated field `KPI_SALES` & `KPI_PROFIT` following the logic above

The ideia is to use the `forms` with the 2 calculated fields created above, however, the problem it that Tableau only allows to use one variable on `forms` which is my problem, i will have to use 2 variables on this example

There is any other way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by creating fake columns such as sum(0)
so each card would allowed by the chose different variables to put on marks as the picture below shows

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this.  Go to each sheet and click on the Label Card in the Marks Shelf.  Then click the box that says "Allow labels to overlap other marks".  See picture.

[image]